# How to confirm password after encryption

Tags: php, password-hash

So I've managed to encrypt the users password successfully and send it to the DB etc.. I just wanted to know how I would go about decrypting or other methods to check to see if the users input matches the DB password. Everytime the hash is processed a different encrypted password is created.Using PHP 4.3

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="user" id="user">
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();

require_once("connection.php");
require_once("passEncrypt.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$user = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];

$pass = encrypt($password);

echo $pass;

}

?>

    <?php

function encrypt($pass){
// use blowfish algorithm 10 times
$hash_format="$2a$10$";
$salt_length=22;
$salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
// store this in DB
$format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt ;
$hash = crypt($pass, $format_and_salt);
return $hash;
}

function generate_salt($length){
// return 32 character random string
$unique_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
// provides valid characters
$base64_string = base64_encode($unique_string);
// replaces + with .
$mod_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string );
// make string correct length
$salt = substr($mod_base64_string, 0, $length);
return $salt;
}
?>
```

I realise the data isn't sanitized or the PHP secure etc.. I'm just trying to understand how to do this before I implement the code into my actual page.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want to do. Is it correct that you want to do something like `decrypt($pass)` to compare it to `$password`?

Comment: I would use clientside hashing of the password (JavaScript).

Comment: Update PHP to at least 5.5, it was released 20 June 2013, better yet update to PHP 7. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. Using older versions just plays into the hands of attackers, they look for sites using older versions.

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function. Do not use clientside hashing of the password, this needs to be done on the server side.

Comment: @zaph why? Generating a hash on the clientside is way better privacy. The plaintext password should not be on the server, not even in memory.

Comment: If an attacker can see the password sent he can see the password hash sent just as easily. The answer is to use HTTPS for transport security. By having on the server use an iteration count can be used to make trying a password expensive in time which is the current best practice. This is what `Bcrypt`, `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, etc do.

Comment: @zaph of course, https+serverside hashes are fine, but it's not good privacy protection when the server can see the users plaintext password. This is why you should use clientside + serverside hashing.

Comment: @DanFromGermany You are behind on current security best practices, it is imperative that a password hashing cost (time) must be included on the server side. It is much more important to protect the entire user base at-rest logins with a time consuming hash than transient access to the passwords at login. Look at all the huge data breaches and the ones that reveal the most damaging information are the ones that do not use a good password hashing method on the server. The OP is using POST so the passwords will not end up in server logs.

Comment: @zaph If the server is telling me I am not allowed to use a blankspace in my password, then that system is not privacy safe. These checks have to be done on the client. Of course everything you say is correct regarding serverside protection, except that I'm behind in security best practices. I'm a little ahead of you buddy.

Comment: Sure, you can make checks on the client, the is a reasonably good thing to do. But do understand that an attacker has control over the client, he may not even be using the supplied client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109458/discussion-between-danfromgermany-and-zaph).

Answer (score 2):

First: [This is not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Encryption is reversible.

I wouldn't use this code at all:

> ```
> <?php
> function encrypt($pass){
>   // use blowfish algorithm 10 times # blowfish != bcrypt
>   $hash_format="$2a$10$";
>   $salt_length=22;
>   $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
>     // store this in DB
>     $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt ;
>     $hash = crypt($pass, $format_and_salt);
>     return $hash;
>   }
>
> function generate_salt($length){
>   // return 32 character random string
>   $unique_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)); # Insecure RNG
>   // provides valid characters
>   $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_string);
>   // replaces + with .
>   $mod_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string );
>   // make string correct length
>   $salt = substr($mod_base64_string, 0, $length);
>   return $salt;
> }
> ```

Instead, [use the password hashing API](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#php). No reason to reinvent the wheel here.

```
$hash = password_hash($yourPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if (password_verify($yourPassword, $hash)) {
    // Login successful
}
```

> Using PHP 4.3

[Don't use PHP 4](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/on-php-version-requirements.html). If you do, you're totally on your own.